# How to launch ActivityResultLauncher for picking contact?

Tags: android, fragment, registerforactivityresult

I need to get contact info from activity which is out of my app. I read [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin) and try getting info as doc says. I can't understand what argument I must pass to launch method of ActivityResultLauncher.

```kotlin
private val getContact = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()
) { uri: Uri? ->
    Log.d(TAG, uri.toString())
}

....

button.setOnClickListener {
    getContact.launch() // here launch requires argument of type Void?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `null` or use the [extension method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/package-summary#(androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher).launch(androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat)) from `activity-ktx` specifically for `ActivityResultLauncher<Void?>` that means you don't need to pass anything at all:

```
import androidx.activity.result.launch
```